# How to select, map and count data from JSON API with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and am struggling to find the right method for the following:

I have 2 API responses, one is a list of devices, the other one is a list of organizations.
Each device is linked to an organization with an Organization ID.

```
organizations = [
                 {
                  'name': 'Aperture Science Inc.', 
                  'description': 'Just a corporation!', 
                  'id': 1
                 }, 
                 {
                  'name': 'Software Development Inc', 
                  'description': "Making the world's next best app!", 
                  'id': 2
                 }
                ]

devices = [
           {
            'id': 1, 
            'organizationId': 2, 
            'nodeClass': 'WINDOWS_WORKSTATION', 
            'displayName': 'DESKTOP_01'
            },{
            'id': 2, 
            'organizationId': 2, 
            'nodeClass': 'WINDOWS_SERVER', 
            'displayName': 'SERVER_01'
            },{
            'id': 3, 
            'organizationId': 1, 
            'nodeClass': 'WINDOWS_WORSTATION', 
            'displayName': 'DESKTOP_0123'
            }
           ]
```

The OrganizationID in devices = the id in organizations.
I want to get a result with the number of Servers and workstations respectively for each organizations, like this:

```
results = [
           { 
            'Organization Name' : 'Aperture Science Inc.', 
            'Number of Workstations': 1, 
            'Number of Servers': 0,
            'Total devices': 1
           }, 
           { 
            'Organization Name' : 'Software Development Inc', 
            'Number of Workstations': 1, 
            'Number of Servers': 1,
            'Total devices': 2
           }
```

I started with this

```
wks_sum = sum(d.nodeClass == "WINDOWS_WORKSTATION" for d in devices)
print(wks_sum)
```

but I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'nodeClass'

and at the very end I convert and save in a csv file:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```

I am struggling doing the count of each device types and also to map devices to the right organization name and would really appreciate some help :)

EDIT:

Thanks to @Vincent, I could come up with:

```
    for device in devices:
    for organization in organizations:
        organization["workstations"] = organization.get("workstations", [])
        organization["servers"] = organization.get("servers", [])
        if device["organizationId"] != organization["id"]:
            continue
        if device["nodeClass"].__eq__("WINDOWS_SERVER"):
            organization["servers"].append(device["nodeClass"])
        elif device["nodeClass"].__eq__("WINDOWS_WORKSTATION"):
            organization["workstations"].append(device["nodeClass"])
        break

results = [
    {
        "Organization Name": organization["name"],
        "Number of Workstations": len(organization["workstations"]),
        "Number of Servers": len(organization["servers"]),
        "Total devices": len(organization["workstations"] + organization["servers"]),
    } for organization in organizations
]


# print(f"{results = }")
print(results)


# convert and save in a csv file

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: The fact that it's from a JSON API is irrelevant. Once you've converted the response to a list of dictionaries, it doesn't matter where it came from.

Comment: Dictionary elements are accessed using `[]`, not `.`. So it's `d['nodeClass']`.

Comment: You can convert the two lists to pandas dataframes. Then you can join them to get the result you want.

Comment: @Barmar How do you do the join? like this? `pd.merge(df_org, df_dev, left_on='id', right_on='organizationId')`. I'm pretty new to Pandas myself.

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: `df_org.join(df_dev, ...)`

Comment: @Barmar Oh, `df_org.set_index('id').join(df_dev.set_index('organizationId'))`. I was confused because the indexes and columns don't match.

Comment: I'm not really a pandas expert, so I don't provide detailed answers. You can use the `on` argument to specify the column in `df_org`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah yeah, that makes more sense. `df_org.join(df_dev.set_index('organizationId'), on='id', rsuffix='_device')` worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will achieve you goal:

```
organizations = [
     {
      'name': 'Aperture Science Inc.', 
      'description': 'Just a corporation!', 
      'id': 1
     }, 
     {
      'name': 'Software Development Inc', 
      'description': "Making the world's next best app!", 
      'id': 2
     }
]

devices = [
    {
    'id': 1, 
    'organizationId': 2, 
    'nodeClass': 'WINDOWS_WORKSTATION', 
    'displayName': 'DESKTOP_01'
    },{
    'id': 2, 
    'organizationId': 2, 
    'nodeClass': 'WINDOWS_SERVER', 
    'displayName': 'SERVER_01'
    },{
    'id': 3, 
    'organizationId': 1, 
    'nodeClass': 'WINDOWS_WORSTATION', 
    'displayName': 'DESKTOP_0123'
    }
]

for device in devices:
    for organization in organizations:
        organization["workstations"] = organization.get("workstations", [])
        organization["servers"] = organization.get("servers", [])
        if device["organizationId"] != organization["id"]:
            continue
        if device["displayName"].startswith("SERVER_"):
            organization["servers"].append(device["nodeClass"])
        elif device["displayName"].startswith("DESKTOP_"):
            organization["workstations"].append(device["nodeClass"])
        break
        
results = [
    {
        "Organization Name": organization["name"],
        "Number of Workstations": len(organization["workstations"]),
        "Number of Servers": len(organization["servers"]),
        "Total devices": len(organization["workstations"] + organization["servers"]),
    } for organization in organizations
]


print(f"{results = }")
```

Result:

```
[{'Organization Name': 'Aperture Science Inc.', 'Number of Workstations': 1, 'Number of Servers': 0, 'Total devices': 1}, {'Organization Name': 'Software Development Inc', 'Number of Workstations': 1, 'Number of Servers': 1, 'Total devices': 2}]
```

Indeed you can do it using obscure lib such as pandas, but I think a good slow code like this is better to know what is done and easier to modify if needed.

To deal with a huge amount of data, you should dump into two sql tables using sqlite3 for example and deal with SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vincent !
I had to twist it a little bit as the workstation and servers names can pretty muh be anything:

        if device["nodeClass"].__eq__("WINDOWS_SERVER"):
            organization["servers"].append(device["nodeClass"])
        elif device["nodeClass"].__eq__("WINDOWS_WORKSTATION"):
            organization["workstations"].append(device["nodeClass"])
        break

Comment: I am observing a strange behaviour with the code, sometimes it is sending me an error:

"Number of Workstations": len(organization["workstations"]),
KeyError: 'workstations'

What could be the reason?
I am using the exact same code and the key is defined and there are values in there.

Comment: It means the key is missing, try to use the get method insteed from dictionary value: `len(organization.get("workstations", [])`